# Dynamic sql and case statement issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have one dynamic sql where i use case with variable but it is giving error.

here is the snip.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)         
DECLARE @isrepaired INT

SET @isrepaired=1
SET @SQL=@SQL+'SELECT *              
                FROM   (SELECT Row_number()            
                               OVER (            
                               ORDER BY [bbajobs].[customername] ) AS            
                               RowNumber,            
                               [bbajobs].[jid],            
                               ourfeedback.rating,            
                               ourfeedback.adddates as [Add Dates]
                   ,Repaired=
                case '+CAST(@isrepaired as varchar)+' when 1 then ''Yes''
                case '+CAST(@isrepaired as varchar)+' when 0 then ''No''          
                END
                        FROM  dbo.bbajobs '
```

i am sending value for isrepaired at runtime. cant we write the statement like this way? please guide me where to fix. thanks

### UPDATE

dynamic sql was my requirement so guide me how to do it in dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)         
DECLARE @isrepaired INT

SET @isrepaired=1
SET @SQL=@SQL+'SELECT *              
                FROM   (SELECT Row_number()            
                               OVER (            
                               ORDER BY [bbajobs].[customername] ) AS            
                               RowNumber,            
                               [bbajobs].[jid],            
                               ourfeedback.rating,            
                               ourfeedback.adddates as [Add Dates]
                   ,Repaired=
                case '+CAST(@isrepaired as varchar)+' when 1 then ''Yes''
                '+CAST(@isrepaired as varchar)+' when 0 then ''No''          
                END
                        FROM  dbo.bbajobs '
```

my dynamic sql look like

```
SELECT *              
                FROM   (SELECT Row_number()            
                               OVER (            
                               ORDER BY [bbajobs].[customername] ) AS            
                               RowNumber,            
                               [bbajobs].[jid],            
                               ourfeedback.rating,            
                               ourfeedback.adddates as [Add Dates]
                   ,Repaired=
                case 1 when 1 then ''Yes''
                when 0 then ''No''          
                END
                        FROM  dbo.bbajobs '
```

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL here?

Comment: dynamic sql was my requirement so guide me how to do it in dynamic sql

Comment: Dynamic SQL is never a requirement in and of itself. It is a tool that is used to meet your real requirement. There is nothing in your question which shows you require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no obvious need for dynamic SQL here. Just use

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY [bbajobs].[customername] ) AS RowNumber,
               [bbajobs].[jid],
               ourfeedback.rating,
               ourfeedback.adddates                                    AS [Add Dates],
               Repaired= CASE @isrepaired
                           WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
                           WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
                         END
        FROM   dbo.bbajobs) AS T
```

If you do need dynamic SQL for reasons not shown then you should at least first start with a working non dynamic query then convert it.

You are missing a table alias for the derived table and `case ... case ... end` is not valid.

The semantics of the query seem very odd though. Why is the repaired status derived exclusively from the `@isrepaired` variable for all rows?

Comment: dynamic sql was my requirement so guide me how to do it in dynamic sql

Comment: Hi I am still a novice in sql, how does one decides Dynamic query is needed or not? Like in this question

Comment: @Shad - Dynamic SQL should generally be avoided and only used when there is some reason why static SQL doesn't do what you need. At development time It is difficult to work with queries when they are just strings assembled at runtime and you need to be aware of SQL injection possibilities when using dynamic SQL. The most common good use case is when you need to do something dynamic but the SQL language doesn't allow the dynamic part to be parameterised (replaced with a variable or parameter) - it is also used if the structure of the query itself needs to be variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.  You have two CASE 's.  It should be WHEN.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

```
Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Also, use this instruction to see the code being generated dynamically in a XML window.  Cut and paste into another window to debug.  That way you can verify the syntax.

```
-- Cool instruction ?
SELECT @SQL  as [processing-instruction(TSQL)] FOR XML PATH
```